# Default font family in .NET MAUI

Tags: xaml, maui, .net-maui

Is there a way to simultaneously set the default font family to all text controls? The idea is not to specify a font family for each control separately.

Comment: i don't think there is a common code for all controls. as i noticed the property `FontFamily` is not common. ie Entry has it own and Label has it's own also

Comment: No common way, you will have to manually do it for all the controls...

Comment: What do you mean by each control? Every instance or every class? You cannot set it for every class at once, but for every instance of a control class using Styles.

Comment: The OP said "for all TEXT controls", not property! If he thinks of Label controls, or EditBox controls, yes it could be done in Resources/Styles.xaml file. If he want for each control which have Text property, this must be done separatelly for each controls, in the same Resources/Styles.xaml file.

Answer (score 4):

You could set a variable inside the styles.xaml and set all FontFamilys to that variable

For example:

```
    <System:String x:Key="StrFontFamily">Times New Roman</System:String>

...

    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The be fair, you still set it for each control separately, but all at once with one variable.

If this seems like something that would work for you then the below code is the whole Styles.xaml with the variable defined in it.
Copy it from here into *{Project}/Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml* to test it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    
    <System:String x:Key="StrFontFamily">Times New Roman</System:String>

    <Style TargetType="ActivityIndicator">
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="IndicatorView">
        <Setter Property="IndicatorColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndicatorColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray100}}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="Rectangle"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="BoxView">
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Primary}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="14,10"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DatePicker">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Editor">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ImageButton">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="SeparatorColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="RefreshControlColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Picker">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="ProgressColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ProgressColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="RefreshView">
        <Setter Property="RefreshColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="SearchBar">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
        <Setter Property="CancelButtonColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="SearchHandler">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Shadow">
        <Setter Property="Radius" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
        <Setter Property="Brush" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Offset" Value="10,10" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Slider">
        <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="MinimumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="MaximumTrackColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="SwipeItem">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Switch">
        <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="On">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="OnColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Secondary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Off">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="ThumbColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray400}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TimePicker">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource StrFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray300}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Page" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="{OnPlatform WinUI={StaticResource Primary}, Default={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.NavBarHasShadow" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Black}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray900}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="IconColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TabbedPage">
        <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource White}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="UnselectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" />
        <Setter Property="SelectedTabColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 1):

*If*, with "all text controls", you simply mean all controls that display text, in other words a default font for the entire app, you can simply do that by making it the first font you add when calling `.ConfigureFonts` in your  MauiProgram, e.g.:

```cs
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();

builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("Lato-Regular.ttf", "LatoRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("Lato-Bold.ttf", "LatoBold");
        });
```

LatoRegular is now the default font. You can remove the `FontFamily` property in Styles.xaml for all controls that must use the default font.

Comment: This did not work for me. I set a serif font as both the first and last font added, but I still got a non-serif (default) font when viewing a page.